# Sorting key,value pairs in a perl array data structure according to key(id)

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I am trying to sort key,value pairs present in an array data structure in perl .However,I could not resolve how to sort when there are multiple entries.

Below is my code:

```
  my @users = (
       {id => 1,  name => "Frank"},
       {id => 10, name => "Joe"},
       {id => 5,  name => "Paul"}
      );
```

I want the output to be sorted with respect to id in ascending order:

```
       {id => 1,  name => "Frank"},
       {id => 5,  name => "Paul"},
       {id => 10, name => "Joe"}
```

Below is my effort:

```
  use strict; 
  use warnings;
  use 5.010;
  my @users = 
  (
    {id => 1,  name => "Frank"},
    {id => 10, name => "Joe"},
   {id => 5,  name => "Paul"}
  );

 foreach my $name (keys %users) {

 printf "%-8s %s\n",$users{id},$users{name};
 }
```

Any suggestions would be highly helpful.

Comment: Do you have `@users` or `%users`??? Also, I don't see `sort` anywhere in your code???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have conflicting specifications of your data, but does this do what you need?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @users = (
    { id => 1,  name => "Frank" },
    { id => 10, name => "Joe" },
    { id => 5,  name => "Paul" },
);

for my $item ( sort { $a->{id} <=> $b->{id} } @users ) {
    printf "%-8s %s\n", $item->{id}, $item->{name};
}
```

#### output

```
1        Frank
5        Paul
10       Joe
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have an incorrect understanding of Perl [Hashes](http://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-hashes).

Also use [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; 
use warnings;
use 5.010;
my %users = 
(
  1 => {id => 1,  name => 'Frank'},
  2 => {id => 10, name => 'Joe'  },
  3 => {id => 5,  name => 'Paul' }
);

foreach my $serial (sort {$users{$a}{id} <=> $users{$b}{id}} keys %users) 
{
   printf "%-8s %s\n",$users{$serial}{id},$users{$serial}{name};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using sort:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @users =
(
    { id => 1 , name => "Frank" },
    { id => 10, name => "Joe"   },
    { id => 5 , name => "Paul"  }
);

@users = sort { $a->{id} <=> $b->{id} } @users;

foreach my $user ( @users ) {
    printf "%-8s %s\n" , $user->{id}, $user->{name};
}
```

[edit] changed to sort by ID

Comment: I guess you're getting downvoted because the OP said "I want the output to be sorted with respect to id".

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to use the `nsort_by` function from [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy):

List::UtilsBy: https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( nsort_by );

my @users = (
    {id => 1,  name => "Frank"},
    {id => 10, name => "Joe"},
    {id => 5,  name => "Paul"}
);

foreach my $user ( nsort_by { $_->{id} } @users ) {
    printf "%-8s %s\n" , $user->{id}, $user->{name};
}
```